# Fork and join concept lagging

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, operating-system

This is a sample code which i wrote this just for you to understand my problem which writtens below. 
This is class which has a examplemethod which calculate some value for different a;

```
public class Class1{
public int examplemethod(int a){
     int k = a*2;
     int b=k+1;
     ......some more manipulation 
     return k;
}
}
```

Below class will call the above method parallely

```
public class Class2 extends RecursiveTask<Integer>{
int a=0;
Class1 obj; 
public Class2(int a, Class1 obj){
     this.a = a;
     this.obj=obj;
}  
@Override
protected Integer compute () {
     return obj.examplemethod(a); 
 } 


public static void main(Strings[] args){
   List<Class2> list =new ArrayList<Class2>(); 
   Class1 obj = new Class1();
    for(int i=4;i<7;i++){
       Class2 obj2=new Class2(obj);
       obj2.fork();
       list.add(obj2);
    }
    int arr[]=new int[4];
     int i=0;
    if(list.size>0){
       for(Class2 ob:list){
            arr[i++]= ob.join();
       } 

    }

}
}
```

I am creating three object of class2 in the for loop so suppose 1st fork will compute the value using a=4 but while it is computing in the examplemethod, cpu shedule another thread let say fork 2 with a=5 and save program counter for fork 1 thread, now while computing value using a=5 it changes some variable inside the examplemethod which was earlier changes by fork1, so now my problem is, if examplemethod is resource which was shared among all the object of that class and if one object do some changes in the function and in the middle(thread switching) some other object came and change the same variable then my output will get affected but the problem is i am getting the right answer, so where my concept lagging in parallel threading, Threads will share a common resource so where is my critical section in my code.

Comment: (1) Please make it easier on everyone by adhering to convention for names -- specifically, class names should be in CamelCase, with an initial capital letter.  (2) Your code is invalid.  Among its problems is that it invokes a no-arg constructor for class `class2`, but that class has no such constructor, and that it attempts to use primitive type `int` as a type argument.  That is not an exhaustive list.

Comment: `b=x;` -- what is `b`? If that statement is relevant then you've omitted important details; if not, don't include it.  Also, a very long run-on sentence is extremely hard to decipher.  If you want help please make it easy for others to understand your issue.  Also, `RecursiveTask<int>` is not valid Java.  Please include compilable code.

Comment: i did some changes, kindly remove -1 whoever mark it, if you still want some changes i can do that, i have not provided my actual code i just right sample pseduo so that my problem can be understandable.

Comment: there is a minimum example in the documentation about how to use the [RecursiveTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html#RecursiveTask--).

Comment: A class constructor doesn’t have a `void` return type, further it has to match the class name case sensitively, i.e. `public Class2(int a) { this.a = a; } ` Further, you have to specify the appropriate argument when constructing the object, `new Class2(i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared inside a method are *local variables*, having specific values for the particular method invocation. You should understand that concept independently of multi threading aspects first. E.g. what will the following program print:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(5);
    }

    private static void test(int i) {
        System.out.println("enter test with "+i);
        if(i>0) test(i-1);
        System.out.println("leave test with "+i);
    }
}
```

The local nature of these variables doesn’t change when multiple threads execute the same method. There is no interference between these executions.

Likewise, instance variables, i.e. member variables declared in a class without the `static` modifier. hold values specific to a particular object instance, hence, if you create multiple instances, they can have distinct values for these variables without affecting each other.

These are the building blocks which are used to build multi-threaded programs without the need to do thread synchronization all the time. If you create distinct objects representing the different tasks to be executed and these tasks execute only methods using these objects and/or their method parameters (method parameters are local variables) to compute results, the tasks are already isolated.

The things you *must not* do, are modifying `static` variables or instance variables of *shared* objects. In your code, there are no shared objects.

Comment: So if i share a object b/w threads and compute the value then i need to use synchronize ? I have updated the code for this please look

Comment: The critical aspect is the *modification* of shared state. In your code, `Class1` has no instance variables and therefore `examplemethod` can’t modify them. If `Class1` had instance variables and `examplemethod` was modifying them, using thread safe constructs was necessary, e.g. declaring `examplemethod` as `synchronized`. Then, you have to decide whether the modification is appropriate *semantically*, as you have no control over the order in which the tasks invoke that method.

Answer (score 1):

Which resource is shared between threads in your code?

in short your `class1` is thread safe, because variables defined inside method cannot be changed by another thread.

While `class2` is not - if and only if two threads can use same instance of `class2` at the same time (aka Singleton) and thread changes some instance variable, while another one use it.

You have only one instance variable in `class2` - `int a`.

But in the code I do not see any kind of Singleton or instance variable `"a"`change...

Each thread has a new instance of class2: `Class2 obj2=new Class2();`

(actually it must be kind of `Class2 obj2=new Class2(aValue);`)

Did I miss something there?